# Adding content to div causes it to shift?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the following code, I have a simple page setup, but as soon as I add something to the `div` with class `page` the whole main page `div` shifts downwards?

try adding `<h1>hello</h1>` to the `div` with class `page`.

what is the problem, the div should remain there and simply `<h1>hello</h1>` should be added!

code: https://jsfiddle.net/5sx0sj2q/

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
}
.sidebarcontainer{
  width: 300PX;
  height: 2000px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}
.innersidebarcontainer{
  position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.sidebar{
  width: 293px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 500px;
  top: 1px;
  position: absolute;
}
.mainpage{
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  height: 2000px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.page{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
.footer{
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #031003;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebarcontainer">
            <div class="innersidebarcontainer">
                    <div class="sidebar">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--
    --><div class="mainpage">
        <div class="page"></div>
    </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there's a trick for that :

```
.mainpage{
  vertical-align : top; // Add this
}
```

Also, change the H1 display property :

```
h1{
  display : inline-block;
}
```

All the elements stay up where they should be. The joys of CSS.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmtqy5mk/6/)

Comment: But what was the problem! and how this solves the problem?

Comment: But if you still add `<h1>something</h1>` it still shifts down a little bit?

Comment: Ah, that's because `h1` has an embedded margin-top, if you cancel it, it works : https://jsfiddle.net/cmtqy5mk/4/ But float, inline-block and other traditional CSS properties are a complete mess anyway. Flex (flexbox) is the solution to all layout problems.

Comment: But shouldn't the entire h1 along with margins remain inside the page div?

Answer (score 1):

Is normal, display: inline-block add a little space between elements (and you have no more space).
Use float left instead and your code works.

Comment: Float, inline-block and other traditional CSS properties are a mess anyway. Flex is the solution to all layout problems.